# List of objects to numpy array

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, numpy

For one of my project in image processing, I need to use key points. To compute them, I found that OpenCV was quite fast and convenient to use. But, when computing the key points of an image with, for example, the FAST algorithm we receive an array of [KeyPoint objects](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html).

When I get those key points, I would like to only take their coordinates, not the additional information (angle, etc.). Those coordinates will be used to make several computation with numpy. The problem is the conversion time from an array of KeyPoint to a numpy array. It takes approximately 60% of the total execution time. Any suggestion how to improve the loop below?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image_cv2 = cv2.imread("sample.jpg")
fast = cv2.FastFeatureDetector(threshold=25)
keypoints = fast.detect(image_cv2)

n = len(keypoints)
cd_x = np.zeros(n, dtype=np.int)
cd_y = np.zeros(n, dtype=np.int)
for i in xrange(0, n):
    cd_x[i] = keypoints[i].pt[0]
    cd_y[i] = keypoints[i].pt[1]
```

PS: I tried to use np.vectorize but I did not notice any improvement. For information, the number of key points by image is often around 5 000.

**Update:**
As some people pointed out, the simple assignation from keypoints to numpy array should be quite fast. After some tests, it is true that it is very fast. For example, for a dataset of 275 images, with 1 thread, the complete execution time is 22.9s, with only 0.2s for the keypoints->numpy to execute, and around 20s is spent by cv2.imread().

My mistake was to use too many threads at the same time, as each core was not used at least at 80% I kept increasing their quantity until this arbitrary limit, which slowed down the loop execution. Thank you everyone to make me open my eyes on a stupid mistake elsewhere in the code!

Comment: Is `keypoints` a list of objects, or a `numpy` array with `dtype=object`?  What do you mean by `vectorize`?  Using the `np.vectorize` function, or something else?

Comment: Sometimes a comprehension is faster: `cd_x=np.array([k.pt[0] for k in keypoints])`

Comment: @hpaulj keypoints is a list of objects, not a numpy array. I've updated the title and the body, I was talking about np.vectorize as I do not know how to truly vectorize in python.

Comment: When you say it takes 60% of the execution time, are we talking seconds or minutes? Taking 2 integers from 5000 objects and sticking them in numpy arrays surely won't take too long, and will scale linearly with more objects.

Comment: `np.vectorize` just wraps a loop around your function.  It's a convenience tool, not a way of speeding up the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A trial case:

```
In [765]: class Keypoints(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.pt=[1.,2.]
   .....:         
In [766]: keypoints=[Keypoints() for i in xrange(1000)]
In [767]: cd=np.array([k.pt for k in keypoints])
In [768]: cd
Out[768]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.],
       [ 1.,  2.],
       [ 1.,  2.],
       ..., 
       [ 1.,  2.],
       [ 1.,  2.],
       [ 1.,  2.]])
In [769]: cd_x=cd[:,0]
```

In timeit tests, the `keypoints` step takes just as long as the `cd` calculation, 1ms.

But the 2 simpler iterations

```
cd_x=np.array([k.pt[0] for k in keypoints])
cd_y=np.array([k.pt[1] for k in keypoints])
```

takes half the time.  I was expecting the single iteration to save time.  But in these simple cases, the comprehension itself takes only half of the time, the rest is creating the array.

```
In [789]: timeit [k.pt[0] for k in keypoints]
10000 loops, best of 3: 136 us per loop
In [790]: timeit np.array([k.pt[0] for k in keypoints])
1000 loops, best of 3: 282 us per loop
```

Comment: I just edited my post, you were right! Now the bottleneck is `cv2.imread()`, but I have no real hope to reduce it (loading with the flag cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE is 2x faster, but that's all). Thank you for your help.